# There's no place for entering basic username and password on Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure-data-studio

When creating a new connection in Azure Data Studio the only options are

- sql login - which authenticates through my O/S logged in user *not* username/password
- Windows auth (i'm on mac..)
- Azure AD

[image]

So how do i connect using username/password?

This is latest Azure Data Studio 1.43.0

Comment: See if this doc helps: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/developer-portal-basic-authentication.md

Comment: @Naveen That article refers to the _Developer Portal_ not the _Azure Data Studio_